# Rails how to show an image after every 2 records in index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my index.html.erb and on there shows all recipes that are in the db. But I want to now be able to show an image from `app/assets/images` that I have after every 2 recipes. How could that be done?

index.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'recipes_list', collection: @recipes, as: :recipes %>
```

recipes_list.html.erb

```
<a href="<%= url_for(recipes) %>">
  <article>
    <h2 class="recipe-name"><%= recipe.name %></h2>
  </article>
</a>
```

Solution by using `each_with_index`

```
  <% @recipe.each_with_index do |recipe, index| %>
 
    <h2 class="recipe-name"><%= recipe.name %></h2>
    <% if (index + 1) % 2 == 0 %>
      <div class="photo"><%= image_tag ("recipe.jpg")%></div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Can't you just use `each_with_index` and then use the index in the loop to show the image if it matches the interval you want to show it on?  Can you show your each loop code (edit the question to add it).

Comment: you can try the modulo function. initiate a variable before the loop i = 0 then in loop if (i%2).zero? then show the image and increment the i by 1.

Comment: @RockwellRice thank you for suggesting ```each_with_index``` that worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in_groups_of` function to do this.

```
<% @recipes.in_groups_of(2, false).each do |group| %>
  <!-- Anything here will appear BEFORE every 2-recipe group -->

  <% group.each do |recipe| %>
    <div class="recipe"><!-- render recipe --></div>
  <% end %>

  <!-- Anything here will appear AFTER every 2-recipe group -->
  <div class="photo"><!-- photo here after recipes --></div>
<% end %>
```

This will give you a repeating set of `photo|recipe|recipe` groups.

Comment: thank you! I see this works when I try it but I am looking for set of ```recipe|recipe|photo``` how can I do that way? I tried to flip it but kept getting ```undefined method in recipe ```

Comment: Just move the photo part below the `group.each` block. I'll update the answer to show you.